# Android build "__pure2" redefined

Tags: android, android-ndk

I just installed the latest version of Android NDK (r11b) on a new machine. When I compile my C++ code, I get an error that "__pure2" has been redefined. It appears include file `math.h` includes `sys/cdefs.h`. Both of them unconditionally define a macro called "__pure2" and both of them define it differently.

The same code works fine on my older machine. Upon investigation, it appears on my machine $ndk\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include\sys\cdefs.h does not have any definition of "__pure2." Looks like someone introduced this recently. Wondering if anyone else has seen this problem.

For now, I have just commented the macro definition in `sys/cdefs.h`. Is there a better way to fix this? Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [bug ticket](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62020) tracking this issue, actually. You might want to follow it for further updates, but it looks like it will be fixed in NDK r12. I would probably opt for using #ifndef to work around it as mentioned in the ticket comments.

```
#ifndef __pure2
  #define __pure // whatever the original definition is
#endif
```